# Merge [audioqueue] and [audioqueueservices] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The tags [audioqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueue) and [audioqueueservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueueservices) both refer to the AudioQueue APIs in the AudioToolbox framework for OS X and iOS.

I suggest [audioqueueservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueueservices) is made a synonym of [audioqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueue).

[audioqueueservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueueservices) does have a wiki unlike [audioqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueue) but I believe [audioqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audioqueue) is the better tag as its naming fits with similar tags.